# How to bind custome function to swal html in angular?

Tags: angular

I using swal in my angular project and I need call test() function from the html binded to swal when the button clicked but does not work?

```
Swal.fire({
        html: `<button (click)="test()">Test</button>`,
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: this.translateService.instant('Common.Yes'),
        cancelButtonText: this.translateService.instant('Common.Cancel'),
        confirmButtonColor: '#00d68f',
        cancelButtonColor: '#8f9bb3',
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code like this one:

```
 Swal.fire({
    html: `<button id="test">Test</button>`,
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: this.translateService.instant('Common.Yes'),
    cancelButtonText: this.translateService.instant('Common.Cancel'),
    confirmButtonColor: '#00d68f',
    cancelButtonColor: '#8f9bb3',
    didOpen: () => {
      const b = (Swal.getHtmlContainer() as any).querySelector('#test')
      b.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        this.test();
      });
    },
  });
```